# What is the meaning of this class constructor syntax?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, constructor, key

What is the meaning of these two lines ?

```dart
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit(initialState) : super(initialState); // this line
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key); // and this line

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

I understand that they are constructors, but I'm having troubles understanding the syntaxe, and one additional question would be, what does keys exactly do in flutter ?*

Comment: can  you include code-snippet instead of code-image, 1st snippet it depends on parent `CounterState`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I understand that, but what does that line do still

Comment: you are taking a instance using constructor and passing to parent class.  And for Widget you are passing a key. Can you include `CounterState` as well,

Comment: [When to Use Keys - Flutter Widgets 101 Ep. 4](https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc)